# Combine multiple rows into one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query to fetch me slots a worker is free. The SQL Schema for '**works**' table is as follows:

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------+
|   workID   | workerID | workerType | workTime |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+
| 0000000001 |        1 | agents     |        1 |
| 0000000002 |        1 | agents     |        2 |
| 0000000003 |        1 | agents     |        4 |
| 0000000004 |        1 | agents     |        4 |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Another table '**worker**' is as:

```
+----------+------------+
| workerID | workerName |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | John Doe   |
+----------+------------+
```

I need the output as follows:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| workerType | timeslot1 | timeslot2 | timeslot3 | timeslot4 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| John Doe   | Occupied  | Occupied  | Free      | Occupied  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

But by my query, if I `GROUP BY wo.workerID` then I get

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| workerName | timeslot1 | timeslot2 | timeslot3 | timeslot4 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| John Doe   | Free      | Free      | Free      | Occupied  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**MY TRY:**

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33230/4/0)

```
SELECT wo.workerName,
   CASE
    WHEN w.workTime = 1 THEN 'Occupied'
    ELSE 'Free'
   END AS timeSlot1,
   CASE
    WHEN w.workTime = 2 THEN 'Occupied'
    ELSE 'Free'
   END AS timeSlot2,
   CASE
    WHEN w.workTime = 3 THEN 'Occupied'
    ELSE 'Free'
   END AS timeSlot3,
    CASE
    WHEN w.workTime = 4 THEN 'Occupied'
    ELSE 'Free'
   END AS timeSlot4
FROM works AS w
INNER JOIN workers AS wo ON wo.workerID = w.workerID
WHERE w.workerType = 'agents' AND
  w.workerID = 1
GROUP BY wo.workerID;
```

Comment: Your Case statements aren't distinguishing by WorkID.   They are all looking at the same row.

Comment: Ya so that's the point, even if the worker is busy at one given workTime across jobs I want to return it as Occupied else Free

Comment: Why do you need to pivot the data in the RDBMS?  Can't you just join the tables and pivot (if so desired) in your application code?

Comment: @TabAlleman: If I don't use GROUP BY, I get correct output with multiple rows for each workID. But I want to combine it into one result

Comment: @Abhik's code below is the correct fix for this, but it's important to note that if you are not aggregating via a formula like `sum()`, `max()`, `avg()`, etc.. then you must include those fields in your GROUP BY. Lord only knows what MySQL might decide to aggregate by if you don't. Which is why you are getting such strange indecipherable results. Any other RDBMS would just throw down a big fat error on this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `max()` function for pivoting

```
SELECT wo.workerName,
       max( CASE
        WHEN w.workTime = 1 THEN 'Occupied'
        ELSE 'Free'
       END) AS timeSlot1,
       max(CASE
        WHEN w.workTime = 2 THEN 'Occupied'
        ELSE 'Free'
       END) AS timeSlot2,
       max(CASE
        WHEN w.workTime = 3 THEN 'Occupied'
        ELSE 'Free'
       END) AS timeSlot3,
        max(CASE
        WHEN w.workTime = 4 THEN 'Occupied'
        ELSE 'Free'
       END) AS timeSlot4
FROM works AS w
INNER JOIN workers AS wo ON wo.workerID = w.workerID
WHERE w.workerType = 'agents' AND
      w.workerID = 1
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm. Can you explain how does max() work for strings?

Comment: For each group it will need to see the `max()` and using case when we are just assigning the value as we want, so that the data aggregation is done on max values.

Comment: Problem with this is it wouldn't work if you added more agents or data

Comment: You need to do group by `w.workerID ` if you want it for all `workerID`, and by removing the  where `w.workerID = 1`

Comment: Right, at this point I wanted to run this query for particularly which user had been selected, hence the WHERE clause

Comment: Yep that will work, no harm in putting the group by in anyway for future proofing and workerID = 1 can be removed / edited as needed

Comment: Comparing strings like this is a bad practice and should not be implemented in production. It's error prone on changes. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33230/11

```
SELECT wo.workerName,
       IF(SUM(IF(w.workTime = 1,1,0)),'Occupied','Free') AS timeSlot1,
       IF(SUM(IF(w.workTime = 2,1,0)),'Occupied','Free') AS timeSlot2,
       IF(SUM(IF(w.workTime = 3,1,0)),'Occupied','Free') AS timeSlot3,
       IF(SUM(IF(w.workTime = 4,1,0)),'Occupied','Free') AS timeSlot4
FROM works AS w
INNER JOIN workers AS wo ON wo.workerID = w.workerID
WHERE w.workerType = 'agents' AND
      w.workerID = 1
GROUP BY w.workerID
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from `@Abhik Chakraborty` may be working for this particular case, but if you ever change the strings for example Occupied will become Busy you are going to get Free as a result from `MAX()`.

This is because `MAX()` compares strings on a char-by-char basis. You should assign an integer value and then apply a function on it.

His method would fail:
Whenever `Occupied`'s first character would be smaller than `Free` character. For example rename `Occupied` to `Busy`.

```
-- How it works right now

 select greatest('occupied','free');
 greatest 
----------
 occupied

-- How the behaviour would change if we rename occupied to free

select greatest('busy','free');
 greatest 
----------
 free
```

To prevent this case it is safer to use this method:

```
SELECT
    workerName, 
    CASE WHEN timeSlot1 = 1 THEN 'Occupied' ELSE 'Free' END AS timeSlot1,
    CASE WHEN timeSlot2 = 1 THEN 'Occupied' ELSE 'Free' END AS timeSlot2,
    CASE WHEN timeSlot3 = 1 THEN 'Occupied' ELSE 'Free' END AS timeSlot3,
    CASE WHEN timeSlot4 = 1 THEN 'Occupied' ELSE 'Free' END AS timeSlot4
FROM(
    SELECT 
        wo.workerName,
        MAX(CASE WHEN w.workTime = '1' THEN 1 END) AS timeSlot1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN w.workTime = '2' THEN 1 END) AS timeSlot2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN w.workTime = '3' THEN 1 END) AS timeSlot3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN w.workTime = '4' THEN 1 END) AS timeSlot4
    FROM                                      
        works AS w
        INNER JOIN workers AS wo ON wo.workerID = w.workerID
    WHERE 
        w.workerType = 'agents' AND
        w.workerID = 1
    GROUP BY wo.workerName
    ) foo;
```

**Important Note**

Your `workTime` column should not be type of `varchar(n)` as well. This is error prone because it compares strings by characters.

```
select greatest('211'::varchar, '29'::varchar);
 greatest 
----------
 29
```

I don't think it would be your expected result.

Comment: This is good as well. However setting the text is in my hands and it is definitely to be shown as Occupied and Free as per requirements. So Abhik's answer would definitely be choice #1. Also, my workTime column is of type TINYINT(1)

Comment: From your SQLFiddle ` `workTime varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL`. Remember, that the text is in your hand as long as it is in your hand. If you pass the code to anybody else, or any logic is supposed to be changed - unexpected behaviour could happen.